# Package ‘randomForest’ R defining variable importance in advance

Tags: r, random-forest

I am planning to build 5 successive random forests (RF) on a same data using r 'randomForest' package. I am leveraging work done as per the [page](https://sites.google.com/site/houtaodeng/publications).

while building the first RF, each X variable should have equal chance of getting selected when that RF decides to split the data at any node.

But during the next RFs, chances of each variable getting selected for a split should be based upon variable importance given by the earlier RF. For example, if

RF1$importance is

```
    MeanDecreaseGini
X1         3.3182386
X2         0.6457600
X3         0.6196704
X4         0.5687371
X5         1.6559662
X6         0.4337502
X7         0.5900012
X8         0.4284394
X9         0.8748509
X10        0.4065861
```

then during RF2, X1 variable should have more probability of getting selected and so on. How can i make RF to choose variables for a split based upon some predefined variable importance array?

I know mtry parameter allows us to specify "Number of variables randomly sampled as candidates at each split.", but i want to specify probability of selecting each variable.

----------------update 1-------------------------------

adding sample code

```
library(randomForest)
require(rpart)
fit <- randomForest(Kyphosis ~ Age + Number + Start,   data=kyphosis)
fit$mtry
```

above code will fit a random forest for a classification problem. But lets say i want to increase probability of selecting variable "Age" for any split. Right now each variable has an equal chance of getting selected. How can i achieve that?

Comment: Why aren't you going to the pages cites in that link? (And this is really OT since you are asking for stats-consultation.)

Comment: what do you mean by "OT"? i dont think it is stats-consultation as I am not asking to solve statistical problem. I need programming help with a package and i feel that this question can be answered by stackoverflow experts.

Comment: Maybe I should have written the I thought you really _needed_ statistical consultation. Furthermore, you provided no code or example for testing, so it didn't seem like a serious coding request.

Comment: i added some code as per your suggestion.

Comment: My _suggestion_ was to get statistical help. My explanation for why no one bother to reply was that it didn't look like a serious effort at composing an SO.

Comment: what do SO and OT mean?

Comment: SO ? .... look at the name of this website.

Comment: @user2543622 OT = off topic

Comment: I don't have a lot of experience on this but I don't think this is possible. I would recommend you just code up a new function yourself. The logic isn't that hard and you can add all the levers you want.

Comment: Check out "[Guided Random Forest in the RRF Package](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/45301435/GRF.pdf)" (in the link you provided). The author explains how he has created the [RRF package](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RRF/index.html) for this purpose, and the paper has a nice, short example of use.